# Python - Creating multiple slices of data frame based on DATETIME column to export to multiple CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, slice

I have a master dataframe that I am trying to slice into multiple smaller dataframes using df.loc and basing those slices off the datetime column as seen below:

```py
jan_2021 = merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Value_Date'] > '2021-1-1') & (merged_df['Value_Date'] <= '2021-1-31')]
feb_2021 = merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Value_Date'] > '2021-2-1') & (merged_df['Value_Date'] <= '2021-2-28')]
mar_2021 = merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Value_Date'] > '2021-3-1') & (merged_df['Value_Date'] <= '2021-3-31')]
apr_2021 = merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Value_Date'] > '2021-4-1') & (merged_df['Value_Date'] <= '2021-3-31')]
```

I need to continue doing this until Feb 2023. Is there a faster way of iterating through the datetime column in a loop of some sort, instead of having to write out each datetime range for each slice?

Secondly, I would also like to write each sliced data frame to a CSV file.

```py
jan_2021.to_csv(output_filepath_csv+'Jan21.csv',index=False)
feb_2021.to_csv(output_filepath_csv+'Feb21.csv',index=False)
```

Again, is there a way to loop through the data frames? I'm guessing putting them in a list and looping through the list?

Comment: it seems like you could [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) month and year, then iterate over the groups?

Comment: Are you able to mock that up? I'm having trouble with grouping by month and year.

Answer (score 0):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": [
            "2021-1-1",
            "2021-1-2",
            "2021-2-3",
            "2021-2-7",
            "2021-3-11",
            "2021-4-19",
            "2021-4-22",
        ],
        "col1": [1, 3, 9, 4, 2, 8, 7],
        "col2": [4, 3, 7, 5, 4, 9, 1],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and Python standard library's [strptime and strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```py
import datetime

# Add new columns "year" and "month"
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df["year"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: x.year)
df["month"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: x.month)

# Use a dict comprehension to slice dataframe
# keys: Jan21, Feb21, Mar21, Apr21
# Access slices like: dfs["Mar21"], for instance
dfs = {
    datetime.datetime.strptime(f"{year_and_month[0]}-{year_and_month[1]}", "%Y-%m")
    .strftime("%b%y"): sub_df.drop(columns=["year", "month"])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    for year_and_month, sub_df in df.groupby(["year", "month"])
}

# Save to disk
for month, sub_df in dfs.items():
    sub_df.to_csv("path_to_dir" + f"/{month}.csv", index=False)

# In path_dir: Jan21.csv, Feb21.csv, Mar21.csv, Apr21.csv
```